# SQL - Finding Duplicate Records based certain criteria

Tags: sql

I have these records in the table - `employee_projects`

| id | employee_id | project_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | emp1 | proj1 | VERIFIED |
| 2 | emp2 | proj2 | REJECTED |
| 3 | emp1 | proj1 | VERIFIED |
| 4 | emp1 | proj3 | REJECTED |
| 5 | emp2 | proj2 | REQUIRED |
| 6 | emp3 | proj4 | SUBMITTED |
| 7 | emp4 | proj5 | VERIFIED |
| 8 | emp4 | proj6 | VERIFIED |
| 9 | emp3 | proj4 | REQUIRED |

Here are the criteria for determining duplicates:

1. Same employee ID, same project ID under the same status (Example: rows 1 and 3 are duplicates)
2. Same employee ID, same project ID but in different status (Example: rows 6 and 9 are duplicates).
   An exception to duplication criteria#2 is if one project is REQUIRED and the same project is also REJECTED under the same employee, this is NOT considered a duplicate. For example, rows 2 and 5 are NOT duplicates.

I have a query for the first criterion:

```
select
    emp_id,
    proj_id,
    status,
    COUNT(*)
from
    employee_projects
group by
    emp_id,
    proj_id,
    status
having
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

What I'm struggling to construct is the SQL for the second criterion.

Comment: What if for the same `emp_id`, `proj_id`, you have `status` of 'REJECTED', 'REQUIRED', 'REJECTED', 'REJECTED'...etc, is that considered as duplicated or not?

Comment: the same emp_id, proj_id, you have status of 'REJECTED', 'REQUIRED', 'REJECTED', 'REJECTED' <-- that is not considered duplicate
so long you have a single instance in REQUIRED, everything else can be REJECTED, and still not considered duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe a self join can help you.

```
with t (employee_id ,project_id,status)
as
(
select 'emp1',  'proj1' ,   'VERIFIED'
Union all select 'emp2',    'proj2' ,   'REJECTED'
Union all select 'emp1',    'proj1' ,   'VERIFIED'
Union all select 'emp1',    'proj3' ,   'REJECTED'
Union all select 'emp2',    'proj2' ,   'REQUIRED'
Union all select 'emp3',    'proj4' ,   'SUBMITTED'
Union all select 'emp4',    'proj5' ,   'VERIFIED'
Union all select 'emp4',    'proj6' ,   'VERIFIED'
Union all select 'emp3',    'proj4' ,   'REQUIRED'
)
select
    t.employee_id,
    t.project_id,
    t.status,
    '' as status,
    'criteria#1' as SQL
from
    t
group by
    t.employee_id,
    t.project_id,
    t.status
having
    COUNT(*) > 1
union all
SELECT 
    t.employee_id,
    t.project_id,
    t.status,
    a.status,
    'criteria#2' as SQL
FROM
    t
    left join t as a on 
        t.employee_id = a.employee_id and
        t.project_id = a.project_id
where 
    t.status != a.status and
    concat(t.status,a.status) != 'REQUIREDREJECTED' and
    concat(t.status,a.status) != 'REJECTEDREQUIRED'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select T.emp_id, T.proj_id, T.status, D.dup_cnt
from employee_projects T join
(
  select emp_id, proj_id, count(*) as dup_cnt
  from employee_projects
  group by emp_id, proj_id
  having count(*) > 1 and
    count(distinct case when status in ('REQUIRED', 'REJECTED') then status end) < 2
) D
on T.emp_id = D.emp_id and T.proj_id = D.proj_id
order by T.emp_id, T.proj_id
```

If you want to consider an employee with statuses ('REQUIRED', 'REJECTED', any other statuses) as duplicate, modify the having clause as the following:

```
select T.emp_id, T.proj_id, T.status, D.dup_cnt
from employee_projects T join
(
  select emp_id, proj_id, count(*) as dup_cnt
  from employee_projects
  group by emp_id, proj_id
  having count(*) > 1 and
    (count(distinct case when status in ('REQUIRED', 'REJECTED') then status end) < 2 or count(distinct status) > 2)
) D
on T.emp_id = D.emp_id and T.proj_id = D.proj_id
order by T.emp_id, T.proj_id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4SyoTBbJ).